# C# console roulette game

Tags: c#, beginner, random, console, windows

I made a C# console roulette game. Check it out and give opinions on how to improve or ideas for some other features? It's not finished yet so it has lots of room for improvement. I am very new so take it easy on me.

[GitHub link](https://github.com/alifyandra/roulette/tree/f3db3cf8cd18cad6af804e9989c35b0ace3607ca%20GitHub)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace somekinda
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{          
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;                
    Random ran = new Random();
    var r = new Random();
    string[] color = { "Red", "Black" };                 
    string guess;
    int attempts = 0;
    int bet;
    int money = 500;
    while (money != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Roulette Roller by Alifyandra\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Money:$" + money+"                  Attempts: "+attempts);
        Console.WriteLine("Type in any off the following letters below:");
        Console.WriteLine("a.Even    b.Odd    c.1 to 18    d.19 to 36");
        Console.WriteLine("e.Red     f.Black  g.1st 12     h.2nd 12");
        Console.WriteLine("i.3rd 12");
        guess = (Console.ReadLine());
        //guess verifier
        guess.ToLower();
        bool check = guess == "a" || guess == "b" || guess == "c" || guess == "d" || guess == "e" || guess == "f" || guess == "g" || guess == "h" || guess == "i";                                                     
        if (check == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You did not enter the correct input value(even/odd)");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
        bet:
            Console.WriteLine("Enter an amount to bet");
            bet=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            //bet verifier
            if (bet > money)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You dont have enough money!");
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to try again.");
                Console.ReadKey();                          
                goto bet;
            }
            else {
                money -= bet;
                int roll = ran.Next(0, 37);
                string ranColor = color[r.Next(color.Length)];
                bool even = roll % 2 == 0;
                if ((((guess == "a") && (even == true))) || (((guess == "b") && (even == false)))||((guess == "e") && (ranColor == "Red")||(guess == "f") && (ranColor == "Black")))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The roulette rolled: " + ranColor + " " + roll);
                    Console.WriteLine("You won! +$" + bet * 2 + "!");
                    Console.WriteLine("<Press enter to continue>");
                    money += bet * 2;
                    attempts += 1;
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else if ((guess == "c") && ((roll > 0) && (roll < 19)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The roulette rolled: " + ranColor + " " + roll);
                    Console.WriteLine("You won! +$" + bet * 2 + "!");
                    Console.WriteLine("<Press enter to continue>");
                    money += bet * 2;
                    attempts += 1;
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else if ((guess == "d") && ((roll > 18) && (roll < 37)))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The roulette rolled: " + ranColor + " " + roll);
                    Console.WriteLine("You won! +$" + bet * 2 + "!");
                    Console.WriteLine("<Press enter to continue>");
                    money += bet * 2;
                    attempts += 1;
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }       
                else if ((guess == "g") && (roll > 0 && roll < 13) || (guess == "h") && (roll > 12 && roll < 25) || (guess == "i") && (roll > 24 && roll < 37))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The roulette rolled: " + ranColor + " " + roll);
                    Console.WriteLine("You won! +$" + bet * 2 + "!");
                    Console.WriteLine("<Press enter to continue>");
                    money += bet * 3;
                    attempts += 1;
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The roulette rolled: " + ranColor + " " + roll);
                    Console.WriteLine("You lost! -$" + bet + "!");
                    Console.WriteLine("<Press enter to continue>");
                    attempts += 1;
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    if (money == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You are out of money.");
                        Console.WriteLine("<Press enter to continue>");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.Clear();                
    }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using `goto` statements instead put the code that you dont want to be displayed the second time into an `if statement` that will check if a boolean variable named `firstTime` for example has value of true if it's true than print the information else just skip it and go ahead. Your code will also throw a lot of exceptions like *Formatexception* etc since you are not verifying that the input is an `int` also if the player has more money than 2^31 your program will bug too so use `long` instead.

Your check is a little bit redundant like this `bool check = guess == "a" || guess == "b" || guess == "c" || guess == "d" || guess == "e" || guess == "f" || guess == "g" || guess == "h" || guess == "i";`

Well you already wrote all the possible guesses so you might want to do something like this :

```
bool[] conditions = {guess == "a", guess == "b", guess == "c"....}
```

this allows you to use `Array.IndexOf` this will make your `check` looks like this :

`int check = Array.IndexOf(conditions, true);`

This will return -1 if no condition was met so use into your advantage before you where checking `if(check==false)` now you will do `if(check==-1)` and you will also have the bonus that you already know which specific condition was met because `Array.IndexOf` obviously returns the index of a specific value.

This is also not a good approach

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter an amount to bet");
        bet=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        //bet verifier
        if (bet > money)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You dont have enough money!");
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to try again.");
            Console.ReadKey();                          
            goto bet;
        }
```

instead put this into a while loop that will break only when the user enter's correct values.

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter an amount to bet");
    bet = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    while (bet > money)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You dont have enough money!");
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to try again.");
        Console.ReadKey();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter an amount to bet");
        bet = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

Now one small problem here is that you say "Press Enter to try again" however you are not looking for the specific "Enter" key you accept any keys. If you really want enter to be used do it like this :

```
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to try again.");
            while (!(Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Enter))
            {

            }
```

One major problem are the long `if statements` that include magic numbers as well. Simple fix would be to refactor them into functions with respective names they are really long really hard to read and follow what's going on. Declare the magic number as constant's that's really important. You are also repeating the same text over and over again.

```
                Console.WriteLine("The roulette rolled: " + ranColor + " " + roll);
                Console.WriteLine("You lost! -$" + bet + "!");
                Console.WriteLine("<Press enter to continue>");
```

Instead first refactor the if statements into boolean functions than refactor the entire if into 1 method that way your code will become really clearer and much better. You wont even need to check `if(guess == "some string")` instead make the `check` a `private static int` declared outside of the `static void Main()` this way you can access it in your method without passing it as parameter. Even a better approach would be to create a *static class* with an enum that will work together. Also make the enter check into a method and like this :

```
    private static bool IsEnterPressed()
    {
        while (!(Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Enter))
        {
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and use it everywhere you ask for the *Enter key to be pressed*

```
            if (IsEnterPressed())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter an amount to bet");
                bet = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
```

How to verify the input is not a string :

```
        long bet;
        string tempInput = Console.ReadLine();
        while (!long.TryParse(tempInput, out bet))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter correct input !");
            Console.Write("Enter amount to bet : ");
            tempInput = Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

One last thing you have 2 `Random` variables. You need just one you do `int a = rand.Next(x,y)` anyway you can do it with just 1 variable.

Comment: wow you put that much effort on answering my question, thanks it really helped:D

Comment: can you help me how to make an efficient number checker im trying to add so that you can bet on individual numbers from 1 to 36, i cant seem to do it. im trying to do it by first generating an enumarable array from 1 to 36 but i cant make it check if the guess contains the number from the array.

Comment: I'm mostly a code review user instead of Stackoverflow one. Your question seems to be more relevant for that site. Once you have a working code feel free to tag me under your question comment's so I can take a look at it.However checking if array contains a specific value is trivial just use `array.Contains(your value)`. By the way why would you need an enumerable array anyway , why would you even need an array for that ? Just use a `for` loop 1-36 and check if the current guess has been matched during the iteration of those numbers.

Comment: alright thanks, can you explain me the for loop method?

Comment: As I said implement a working code than I can help you improve it.